# Third Nested Quoting Level in JavaScript with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, quotes

I'm trying to create a RegExp object in JavaScript, but can't because of quoting limitations. I'm searching a part of my HTML document that I've converted into a string, `dataCellsText`, using the `outerHTML` property.

Since it's an HTML document, and I have a tendency to switch between `"` and `'` quotes at times, I figured I would check for both, hence the `["']`. But that `["']` is what's preventing me from doing this. I need to use the constructor, `new RegExp()`, because I need to insert a variable into the expression, meaning that I have to surround the expression with `"` or `'` quotes, both of which are already taken.

Given all this, what I need is a third quoting level. I know of `\"...\"`, but I figure that would interfere with the regex. I also know about `&quot;`, but this is not XML or HTML, so that would not apply either.

The following is the jumbled mess that my regex code has become (the syntax highlighting will further illustrate my point):

```
var regexXSearch = new RegExp("<div id=["'](\w+-*\w*)["']\sdata-cell-x=" + cellCoords.x + ">", "g");
var regexXResults = regexXSearch.exec(dataCellsText);
```

Is there any way out of this quotation avalanche? As previously mentioned, a third type of quote would be what I need, but it looks like there's no such thing that will work in this context.

Comment: You could first convert all ' to " or vice versa prior to your regex query.

Comment: Perhaps, `var regexXSearch = new RegExp("<div id=[\"'](\\w+-*\\w*)[\"']\\sdata-cell-x=" + cellCoords.x + ">", "g");`

Comment: @stribizhev So the `\` escapes would work? I'll give them a shot.

Comment: When initialzing a RegExp via a constructor, you need to double backslashes with shorthand classes, or when you escape metacharacters. (To write ``\``, use `\`\\`\`)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When you say double backslashes and shorthand classes, what are you referring to? Metacharacters I understand. Also, would it be wiser to just not use a constructor? Is this possible: `var regexString = <my regex code here>;` and `var regexXSearch = regexString`?

Comment: @TjGienger You know, I might just do that. That would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: The `\w` is a shorthand class for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.To match a `(` you need `\\(` in a constructor notation. You have to use a constructor notation since you are building a regex dynamically. Also, you must escape the `cellCoords.x` if it contains symbols like `.`, `$` and other metacharacters. Use the one from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): `function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}`

Comment: @stribizhev I see. That makes more sense. Thankfully, cellCoords.x and cellCoords.y will only ever contain integers, but I'll keep the escapes in mind. Thanks! I'll implement the ``\\``.

Comment: @stribizhev I wound up doing this: `var regexXSearch = new RegExp('<div id=["\'](\\w+-*\\w*)["\']\sdata-cell-x=["\']' + cellCoords.x + '["\']>', "g");`, as suggested. Thanks! I have yet to test it out though. We'll see in the near future.

Comment: This is the same suggestion I posted as an answer, just swapped quotes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that the variables only contain integers, you do not need an `escape` function, but you still need to use double backslashes to escape regex metacharacters.

```js
var cellCoordsX = "300"
var regexXSearch = new RegExp("<div id=[\"'](\\w+-*\\w*)[\"']\\sdata-cell-x=[\"']" + cellCoordsX + "[\"']>", "g");
alert("<div id=\"123-Ac_fg\" data-cell-x=\"300\">".match(regexXSearch));
```

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't familiar with the `match()` function. I suppose I still have a lot of regex and string parsing to explore. Thanks for your help!